# Codeigniter with dynamically generated base url getting 303 See Other when posting form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, codeigniter-3

I have a Codeigniter App which was working 100% fine

I had to set it a dynamic base url because it is being both accessed: from a public IP and it is also used in LAN, through 192.*...
I've used the following code (the CI app is in a subfolder of www root):

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = "$root";
```

The dynamic url is working fine, but today (using it from LAN) I've noticed a form is not working (**it was before**). This form has enctype="multipart/form-data" with one file upload field. When submitting this form, I'm getting this in Chrome's console and **nothing is posted. print_r $_POST shows empty**

[image: console log message]

**Is the dynamic base url generating this problem ? Any workaround to solve this ?**

When used the CI app on LAN, I double checked the action url in form's action attr was the one with local IP

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Please check your .htaccess file

Comment: Please show your .htaccess file

Comment: @SAVe there's no .htaccess file present